# How to create an custom application uri scheme/protocol for communication in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, protocols, url-scheme

I wan't to create a custom application protocol to communicate with my website.

For sample, i want to use `app://testcommand` as URI scheme.

In HTML i have a Link like

```html
<a href="app://settings">Open Settings</a>
```

that will open the settings of the application on C#-side.

How i can create these custom scheme easily?

The first idea was an websocket, opened on `localhost` to communicate with the application over the website, but these are to complex with `SSL/TLS` and their certificates.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Accessing hardware. You can't access Scanner-Devices on website's side, an special C# program will be communicate with the scanner. On Intranet's side, you have an `Scan now` button. But it's not relevant why i need this, i want an answer to solve these problem

Comment: The "why" is certainly relevant. Because depending on the "why", your approach may not be necessary or even feasible.